# Ruby installation problems

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm

I am using ubuntu 11.10 and I'm having troubles installing ruby. when I tried to install it it gave out this:

```
Installing Ruby from source to: /usr/share/ruby-rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...

ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #extracted to /usr/share/ruby-rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p125 (already extracted)
Applying patch 'xcode-debugopt-fix-r34840' (located at /usr/share/ruby-rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/p125/xcode-debugopt-fix-r34840.diff)
Error running 'patch -F 25 -p1 -N -f <"/usr/share/ruby-rvm/patches/ruby/1.9.3/p125/xcode-debugopt-fix-r34840.diff"', please read /usr/share/ruby-rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p125/patch.apply.xcode-debugopt-fix-r34840.log
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #autoreconf
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #compiling 
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #installing 
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.21 for ruby-1.9.3-p125 ...
Installation of rubygems completed successfully.
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #importing default gemsets (/usr/share/ruby-rvm/gemsets/)
Install of ruby-1.9.3-p125 - #complete
```

After that I test out ruby and it returns this:

```
The program 'ruby' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby1.8
 * ruby1.9.1
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Please help.

Comment: It appears as though RVM isn't in your PATH. Check your .bash_profile for this line: [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function. If you don't see it, add it. If you do see it, try running 'source ~/.bash_profile'

Comment: Your $PATH is the list of locations (directories) that your system will look for executables. Your system isn't finding ruby because ~/.rvm/* isn't on your $PATH. Sounds like you need to go back and follow all the directions here: https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/

Comment: Sorry - on Ubuntu 11.10 you are most likely looking for ~/.profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met this question before too. The reason it fails is lack of dependent packages.

Run `rvm requirements`, see the requirements and install all packages, including the one under `ruby-head`

For me, I have to install:

`sudo apt-get install curl patch build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion`

After running all packages, install 1.9.3 or Rubinius by typing in:

`rvm install 1.9.3` or `rvm install rbx`

It should go smoothly.

After installation, go to Terminal->Edit->Profile Preference->Title and Command, check `Run command as login shell`. Close, and close terminal window too. Open up a new terminal window, run `rvm --default use 1.9.3`(or others), and close terminal again.

Now open a new terminal, type ruby, it now should give you the right ruby.