# Problems updating new ruby version

Tags: ruby, installation, rvm, patch

I tried to install a new ruby version with rvm on my mac. There were several problems why I choosed to reinstall everything.

There are two versions of ruby.

1. Mac interal ruby -> 1.8.*
2. User verson -> 1.9.1 (need >= 1.9.2)

It is possible to install new version on the local mac version with "sudo rvm install ..."
But when I try it with my user version, this error appears:

```
stvn$ rvm install 1.9.2

info: Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/stvn/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0
info: Downloading ruby-1.9.2-p0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 8296k  100 8296k    0       139k      0  0:00:59  0:00:59   --:--:--  102k

info: Extracting ruby-1.9.2-p0 ...
info: Applying patch '' (located at /)

error: Error running 'patch -F25 -p1 -f <"/"', please check /Users/stevenklar/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p0/patch.apply.*.log

fail: There has been an error applying the specified patches. Aborting the installation.
```

Already tried several solutions posted here in stackoverflow and google. Nothing worked yet.
The errors seems to have something to do with a unvail. path. Means rvm use '' as path instead of for example '/Users/stvn/.rvm/...'

Somebody knows how to fix?

Comment: Can you post the contents of any `/Users/stevenklar/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p0/patch.apply.*.log` ?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you try to install 1.9.3-p125?

Comment: same error, the content of that log is the same error you see above "error: Error running 'patch -F25 -p1 -f <"/"', please check /Users/stevenklar/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-p0/patch.apply.*.log"

Comment: here error form the log: [2012-04-13 15:52:58] patch -F25 -p1 -f <"/"
patch: **** read error : Is a directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two versions of RVM, one in system (1.12.2 - almost new) and one in user home (1.0.2 - ancient).

as the user installation is recommended you should remove everything and start fresh:

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/local/rvm /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh ~/.rvm*
```

open new terminal and make sure there is no rvm in environment:

```
env | grep rvm
```

the output should be empty, if not restart computer,

finally run the installer, as user, without sudo:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto
```

you could also install in guided mode asking for ruby 1.9.2:

```
curl -L get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --auto --ruby=1.9.2
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean to "install the new version on the local Mac version"?

I honestly just removed my supplied version of ruby and installed rvm.

Also, you should always use `rvmsudo`, not `sudo rvm`.

Comment: StvN:~ stevenklar$ rvm -v

rvm 1.0.2 by Wayne E. Seguin (wayneeseguin@gmail.com) [http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]

StvN:~ stevenklar$ rvmsudo rvm -v

rvm 1.12.2 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

Answer (score 0):

`sudo install patch`

Please take a look at this post, and follow all the instructions:

[Ruby installation problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060498/ruby-installation-problems/10060697#10060697)

Install all package needed.

Also sudo is not needed for rvm

Comment: oh yeah you are right. MacOS does not use debian package. Try to run `rvm requirements`, and follow EVERY line in the requirements. I got similar problem too. It was just because of lack of package